# Using Jquery or Javascript, how to make animated text appear one by one when I scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm have an awesome idea for my website header (in this case for only learning purpose not for portofolio, company website, etc).

this is my idea:

**got a blank header and when i start scrolling a words appear one by one like just get typed.**

how can i achieve that ?

ps:

> i just tried on Jquery .scrollTop() thing for the effect and didn't get it . it just show the full sentence not one by one like i want.

i search for this issue but, never get any answer for my absurd question :)

`<div id="text"> the text </div>`

Comment: You can't fade in text nodes, independently.  You will want to put each word you want to fade in/out in it's own span

Comment: you could use the greensock js library, that can be done for sure with that, I have done it before.
Or something like this:
https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/Xyroyd
Else, wrap  each text node into a span and then iterate over them.I can post an example code of this if you like.

Comment: @ptts is greensock a plugin ? if yes , i would skip it cos not interested for plugins :D. btw no need for post your example code :) i like when i find it myself XD it's makes me feel awesome lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can simply do some calculations, and show the the words one by one when scrolling.

Explanation is on the code...

Welcome to SO and happy learning.

```js
//Get the words from $text div and split it by spaces
var textArray = $('#text').text().split(' ');
// Clean inside html text to show after when scroll
$('#text').html(""); 
// Get the size of the array (how many words)
var textArraySize = textArray.length;
// Get the body height minus viewport and divide by how many words
// The reason to decrease the viewport is to show all the word when scroll hits the bottom.
// eg: (1000 - 200)/8 = 200, so a word will be show every 200px scrooled
var textShowAt = ($('body').height() - $(window).height() ) / textArray.length;
// Current word counter index
var textCurrent = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    // Trigger the function when window is scrolled
    showWords();
});

function showWords(){
    //Return if all words is shown
    if(textCurrent >= textArraySize) return; 
    // Get how many pixels have scrolled from top 
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (
      // See if current scrolled size is higher then the current word
      scroll > (textShowAt * textCurrent)
    ) {
        // Append the text to the div
        $('#text').append(textArray[textCurrent] + ' ');
        // Increase textCurrent to show next array key (next word)
        textCurrent++;
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
#text {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text">The text I want to show when scroll</div>
```

Comment: didn't expect for the whole code . but it does help ! thanks